# Display seconds in hh:mm:ss using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to display elapsed time using `moment`.

My function receives an ISO date/time value. Using `moment`, it's easy to calculate the elapsed time but my formatting is not working.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
formatElapsedTime(myIsoDateTimeValue) {

   var momentStart = moment(myIsoDateTimeValue);
   var momentNow = moment();
   var elapsedTime = momentNow.diff(momentStart, 'seconds').toString('H:mm:ss');
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Uncaught RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and
>   36 at Number.toString ()

Comment: `.toString` called on a number with an argument tries to use the argument as a radix: `(255).toString(16)` gives you `0xff`. So the diff returns a number that you're calling `.toString` on with an invalid argument.

Answer (score 2):

`moment.diff` returns a number, `#Number.ToString` returns a number by the base of the argument

You may need to use [moment.duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/)
You can do something like

```
var momentStart = moment(myIsoDateTimeValue);
var momentNow = moment();
var elapsedTime = momentNow.diff(momentStart, 'seconds')

var range = moment.duration(elapsedTime, "seconds");
console.log(range.humanize()) //human readable format
console.log(`${range.hours()}:${range.minutes()}:${range.seconds()}`) // same as format HH:mm:SS
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Moment.js [formatters](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

```
var elapsedTime = moment(momentNow.diff( momentStart )).format('H:mm:ss');
console.log(elapsedTime); // Will output the time in the console with the H:mm:ss format.
```

Comment: `moment.diff` returns a number

Comment: I'm getting an error that reads `Uncaught TypeError: momentNow.diff(...).format is not a function`. Any idea why? `format` is a `moment` function and looks like the other `moment` functions are working. Not sure why this is not working.

Comment: It's not that difficult to handle this manually but I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Sam Updated my answer. You can use the Moment to format the result of the diff.

Comment: @RickyNotaro-Garcia This is acutally working BUT I think it's never going above 23 hours for the hour component. So, if the date I pass into my function is from 5 days ago, I still want to show the total hours or show the number of days.

Comment: @RickyNotaro-Garcia Adding the day did the trick! `format('D:H:mm:ss');` Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked then! I think Daniel solution is probably better though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `.toString` called on a number with an argument tries to use the argument as a radix: `(255).toString(16)` gives you `0xff`. So the diff returns a number that you're calling .toString on with an invalid argument.

You want to do something like this:

```
moment(moment.duration(momentNow.diff(momentStart, 'seconds'), 'seconds')).format('H:mm:ss');
```

Or manually:

```
let diff = momentNow.diff(momentStart, 'seconds');
let hrs = diff / 3600 | 0;
let min = diff / 60 | 0;
let sec = diff % 60;

console.log(`${hrs}:${min}:${sec}`);
```

If you need padding zeros you can use this little helper:

```
let padZeros = n => n < 10 ? `0${n}` : '' + n;
```

Comment: Suspect will run into problems doing it this way due to timezone offset

Comment: @Sam I'd guess charlietfl is probably correct about the timezone causing issues, try the manual method I outlined. Or go with Daniel Krom's answer if that works for you.

Comment: @JaredSmith The solution from Ricky Notaro-Garcia is working!

Comment: @JaredSmith Nope, it's not working. The numbers are wrong! I'm now trying Daniel Krom's solution.

Comment: Second approach doesn't remove hours from minutes calc and minutes from seconds calc